# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to re-learn some basic math and I realize I have forgotten most of it.

> Evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1}$$

Call the terms $S_n$ and the total sum $S$.

$$S_n < \frac{1}{n^3} \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1} = S <  \infty$$

$$S_n = \frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1} = \frac{n}{(n^2+1)^2-1}$$

It has been more than a few years since I did these things.

I would like a hint about what method I should try to look for?

Thanks.

Comment: @Leox : the link you give is focused on $1/(n^4+n^2+1)$, not on $n/(n^4+n^2+1)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

$$n^4+n^2+1=(n^2-n+1)(n^2+n+1)$$

Write $2n$ as $$n^2+n+1-(n^2-n+1)$$

Observe that if $f(m)=m^2-m+1, f(m+1)=?$

which immediately reminds me of Telescoping Series.

Comment: Nice one (+1). Notice that you miss a factor of half.

Comment: ahh, yes...the terms will cancel. Thanks!

Comment: @Galc127, Difference of mind & finger. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Notice, use partial fractions as follows  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1}$$$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n^2-n+1)(n^2+n+1)}$$
$$=\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2-n+1}-\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}\right)$$
$$=\frac 12\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{7}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{13}\right)+\ldots +\left(\frac{1}{n^2-n+1}-\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}\right)\right)$$
$$=\frac 12\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}\right)$$
$$=\frac 12\left(1-0\right)=\color{red}{\frac 12}$$

Comment: Thanks to you too...i remember partial fractions being very useful when dealing with integrals too. I will definitely reread that section in my real analysis book.